# Limit to N cores, but I don't know which ones

Tags: python, cpu, affinity

With `taskset`, I can [limit a process to run on a specific CPU](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23109/15654).

I am submitting jobs through a load scheduling facility on a high performance cluster, and consequentially, when I submit the jobs I don't know:

- on what node they will run
- how many cores that node will have (it might be 16, 48, 64, ...)
- what cores specifically are available
- whether any other of my jobs are running on the same node

Cluster management complains I am using too many CPUs.  This happens in library calls I am making, not in my own code.
Is it possible to force my process to use a maximum of *n* CPUs, *without* specifying exactly which CPUs those are?